# How to make each element to be fully independend with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have two images with text over them.
When I go to one image, the text of that image should disappear.

The code I wrote is ok and works almost fine.

```
<div class="sidebarimagesupermsg"><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" syle="width:100%;" alt="super massage" />
<h3 class="h3sidebarimagesupermsg"><span>super<span class='spacer'></span><br /><span class='spacer'></span>Massage</span></h3>
<div>
<div class="sidebarimage">
<a href="http://www.google.com" title="Workshop for couples"><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.png" syle="width:100%;" alt="Workshop for couples">
<h3 class="h3sidebarimage"><span>Workshop<span class='spacer'></span><br /><span class='spacer'></span>For couples</span></h3>
</a>
<div>
```

Css:

```
.sidebarimage, .sidebarimagesupermsg { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

.h3sidebarimage, .h3sidebarimagesupermsg { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 20px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
.h3sidebarimage span, .h3sidebarimagesupermsg span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 22px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: 2px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   padding: 10px; 
}
.h3sidebarimage span.spacer, .h3sidebarimagesupermsg span.spacer {
   padding:0 5px;
}
.sidebarimage:hover .h3sidebarimage, .sidebarimagesupermsg:hover .h3sidebarimagesupermsg  {
      visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

Please see the demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pikk/7dmzd7yc/

However it works fine for the 1 image. But if I go hover the 2 image, disappears also the text from the 1 image. And that's wrong.

Since I will have a lot of similar images in a sidebar, I don't want to duplicate the CSS code for each image. So I would like to know if there is a solution that permits me to keep only one copy of the css code.

I would like to keep the less CSS code as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not closing your wrapping `<div>` tags. This should work:

```
<div class="sidebarimagesupermsg">
  <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" syle="width:100%;" alt="super massage" />
  <h3 class="h3sidebarimagesupermsg"><span>super<span class='spacer'></span><br /><span class='spacer'></span>Massage</span></h3>
</div>
<div class="sidebarimage">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Workshop for couples"><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.png" syle="width:100%;" alt="Workshop for couples">
      <h3 class="h3sidebarimage"><span>Workshop<span class='spacer'></span><br /><span class='spacer'></span>For couples</span></h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0cjf64p/).

Comment: What a shame :P Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @JCOC611's answer above (about closing your `<div>` tags), you can also greatly simplify your CSS by using element tags instead of custom classes for each item.

In your question you mention:

> I don't want to duplicate the CSS code for each image.

As it currently stands, your markup would need to add a selector for each image/`h3` you add. If you generalize the selectors you can add a (theoretically) infinite amount without touching the CSS.

See this [updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/pkfx6t97/1/) for the simpler CSS.

Comment: That looks much better from a code standpoint, but the visual effect is different. And I have to call the h3 with a class, otherwise it will affect other h3 headings in the wordpress blog.